# Android open URL in browser without left activity

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, web

i have a activity with Media Player playing stream audio and one image linked to a Website. If i click on the link, the audio stream stop because left the activity. How i can to open the browser and don't leave the activity?. Thanks a lot. Piero.

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://testsite.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unless you use a `WebView` within your own app (possibly in a `Fragment`), you are always going to be starting an external web browser app  which will put your `Activity` into a 'stopped' state. The best approach would be to use a `Service` to manage the `MediaPlayer` and ideally handle the web pages yourself instead of starting the externall web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

**Example**

Add `INTERNET` permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add `WebView` to your layout:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Load URL:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

I also recommend reading:
[Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the URL in fragment, Your activity will not stop because fragment inflates on activity view.

Answer (score -1):

You can play audio stream in the background service

Comment: Thanks. Another way?.